# Applying Function to Structure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, structure

Currently, here is my code:

```
% Specify the folder where the files live.
myFolder = 'C:\Users\Irwin\Desktop\Matlab\Scintillator_project\advanced';
% Check to make sure that folder actually exists.  Warn user if it doesn't.
if ~isdir(myFolder)
  errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', 
  myFolder);
  uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
  return;
end

% Get a list of all files in the folder with the desired file name pattern.
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.spe'); 
theFiles = dir(filePattern);
for k = 1 : length(theFiles)
  baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
  fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
end
```

I currently have a structure in which each entry contains a .spe file. I would like to apply the function readSPE (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35940-readspe) to each entry in the structure to convert them from .spe format to a 3D array.

Please help!

Thanks :)

Comment: See: [Loop Control Statements](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html)

Comment: sorry! got that in review and that caught my eye. Forgot that my filter was of...

Comment: Sounds like a situation for `structfun(func,S)`.